# How to return a list of strings that do not match a specific pattern?

Tags: python, regex-negation

I am trying to return all results that do not match a specific pattern from a text file, but I am having difficulty with the syntax.

```
pattern is [A-Z]+\_[A-Z0-9]+\_[0-9]+\_[0-9]+\.[A-Z]{3}
```

Tried the following with no success:

```
'^(?![A-Z]+\_[A-Z0-9]+\_[0-9]+\_[0-9]+\.[A-Z]{3}$).*$'

r'^(?!([A-Z]+\_[A-Z0-9]+\_[0-9]+\_[0-9]+\.[A-Z]{3}).)*$'
```

Below is the code to match the pattern, now I need to find all those entries that do not match.

```
pattern = r'[A-Z]+\_[A-Z0-9]+\_[0-9]+\_[0-9]+\.[A-Z]{3}'

regex1 = re.compile(pattern, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

regex1.findall(text1)
```

Sample of the data is as follows:

plos_annotate5_1375_1.txt   plos_annotate5_1375_2.txt   plos_anno%tate5_1375_3.txt   plos_annotate6_1032_1.txt

The third string is what I would like to pull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check that your regex is not mathing:

```
if regex.match(text1) is None:
    # Do magic you need
```

Comment: Thanks vurmux. Here is the code that worked for me:

Comment: data = regex.split(text1)

for line in data:
    if regex1.match(line) is None:
        print(line)

Answer (score 3):

Why do negation in the regexp if you can do it in Python?

```py
strings_without_rx = [s for s in the_strings if not regex1.search(s)]
```

If you want to scan file lines, you don't even need to store them all, because an open file is an iterable of its lines:

```py
with open("some.file") as source:
  lines_without_rx = [s for s in source if not regex1.search(s)]
# Here the file is auto-closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest of using **negative lookahead assertion** with your pattern:

```
r'(?![A-Z]+\_[A-Z0-9]+\_[0-9]+\_[0-9]+\.[A-Z]{3}[^A-Za-z0-9_+\.-]+)'
```

Without any loop it will give you all patterns that do not match if you use it with `findall` :

```
re.findall(r'(?![A-Z]+\_[A-Z0-9]+\_[0-9]+\_[0-9]+\.[A-Z]{3}[^A-Za-z0-9_+\.-]+)')
```

Comment: When I run the above the results are blank spaces below is the data taken from a .txt file.